# Can you control the print order of Access form with subforms?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007, subform

I have a form in Access 2007 with 2 subforms. Each one has it's own table. All 3 tables have a primary key to link on. The 2 subforms can be linked by the primary key and a second field. Users want to print the form, rather then a report, to review the record data. When the form prints the order is as follows:

```
Main form, [subform1]![record1], [subform1]![record2], etc, [subform2]![record1], [subform2]![record2], etc, last page of the main form.
```

How do I force the form print order to be:

```
Main form, [subform1]![record1], [subform2]![record1], [subform1]![record2], [subform2]![record2], etc, last page of the main form.
```

I've tried setting up the table relationships and checked all the Master-Child links.  The form navigates through records correctly.  I've also looked at print options but didn't see a solution there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a query where you join the master table with the two subtables.

Then apply the requested order and create new form for printing.

Still, a report would be better. Remember to remove any sorting from the query and specify that in the report.